# Populating SQL Server Datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

My program will not update my SQL Server database after executing. When I run my program my DataGridView updates when I insert my information, but it will not update itself in the dataTable.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.dataTable(Id,Name,Age) VALUES('" + idTextBox.Text + "','" + nameTextBox.Text + "','" + ageTextBox.Text + "')";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\employee.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        SqlCommand cmd;

        conn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        this.dataTableTableAdapter.Fill(this.employeeDataSet1.dataTable);
        conn.Close();

        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();

        conn.Open();
        adapt.Update(data);
        conn.Close();

        dataTableDataGridView.DataSource = data;
    }
```

Comment: Of what type is the column `Id` in your table `dbo.dataTable`?  It could be that you have to convert the string from `idTextBox.Text` to be of the same type of `id`. The same may apply for `ageTextBox.Text` and `Age`.

Comment: my id is of type int also same with age

Comment: Welcome to sql injection victim club. `idTextBox.Text` is `hack you';drop table dataTable--`

Answer (score 0):

If you created your DataGridView using the designer which added a dataset, bindingsource, and tableadapter, then your DataGridView should be configured correctly out of the box.  Try commented out these lines:

```
//SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
//DataTable data = new DataTable();
//conn.Open();
//adapt.Update(data);
//conn.Close();
//dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
```

I replicated your button_click code and it works locally for me using Sql Express.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment i assume the cause is the missing conversion. Using [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) you can convert the string to int. Be aware that the `'` have to go as well

```
int id, age; 
bool idIsInt = false, ageIsInt = false;

idIsInt = Int32.TryParse(idTextBox.Text, out id);
ageIsInt = Int32.TryParse(ageTextBox.Text, out age);

if(idIsInt && ageIsInt)
{
 string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.dataTable(Id,Name,Age) VALUES(" 
        + id + ",'" + nameTextBox.Text + "'," 
        + age + ")";
 SqlConnection conn = 
 new SqlConnection(@"Data Source(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\employee.mdf
       ;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

 SqlCommand cmd;
 conn.Open();
 cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```